# Incoming Message Broadcastreceiver not working

Tags: android, android-manifest, message, android-broadcast

Hi everyone .
           i send message to one device and receive this sms in another device's  application.I used Broascast receiver to listen sms body or number .I have taken all permission in manifest but my reciver not call.I have used many thing in 2 days related to manifest like android:priority,android:enabled="true", android:exporte but stiil receiver not working.

```
/* final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();*/
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "in receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("out", "out");
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        Toast.makeText(context, "broad cast reciver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (bundle != null){
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try{
                Log.e("in", "in");
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
```

//                        Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

manifest....
     <

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsListener" android:enabled="true"      android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>

 </application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i uninstalled other application in my device it have also same functionality like my application for example hello  application (check out at play store).Then i installed my application it work great.I think another application set priority or other thing in manifest for new incoming sms.So due to this reason our application broadcast receiver not called

Answer (score 1):

Have your SmsListener extend BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public SmsListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //you code here
    }
}
```

And now you can register your receiver in your main activity:

```
String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

SmsListener smsListener = new SmsListener();

registerReceiver(smsListener, new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED));
```

Remember to unregister it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Priority to 1 made it work for me.  It defaulted to 1000.
I also had to change the name from .SmsListener to .MainActivity$SmsListener but that would probably depend on where you defined the class (in my case it was within the MainActivity).

```
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$SmsListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```